# CLI command to start playing inserted DVD in VLC?

Tags: command-line, vlc, dvd, mediaplayer

I want to add this command into a launcher on the panel or desktop so that I can start the inserted DVD with a single click.

I would prefer this to selecting one of the many options my KDE panel notifier offers, or to opening VLC, going to Media - Open disc etc. (On the other hand I prefer not to enable the option of playing automatically any inserted DVD.)

Comment: Have you seen this page: https://www.maketecheasier.com/mastering-vlc-via-the-command-line-linux/

Comment: command : vlc dvd://

Comment: @GAD3R - won't you post that as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[GAD3R](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/153195/gad3r) gave the answer in a comment to the question:

```
vlc dvd://
```